# Can Bayesian analysis address challenges posed by Gödel's incompleteness theorems?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, formal-systems

In short, according to Gödel's incompleteness theorems, if a formal mathematical system is consistent, then

- it will contain true statements that can neither be proven nor disproven
- it will be unable able to prove its own consistency

**However, can Bayesian reasoning be used to address the challenges posed by Gödel's incompleteness theorems in such systems?**

For instance...

As more and more time goes by and more and more mathematicians fail to discover a contradiction in a given system $S$, can we use Bayes' theorem to update our posterior distribution of belief and increase our confidence that $S$ is indeed consistent? Intuitively, I suspect yes, but the space of possible theorems in $S$ may be infinite and the set of all possible theorems proven up to any point in time will always be finite. Hence, the ratio of "non-contradictory theorems" to "all possible theorems" will be $0$, which does little to inspire my confidence.

Or, as more and more mathematicians fail to prove some conjecture $P$, can we use Bayes' theorem to update our posterior distribution of belief and increase our confidence that $P$ is a Gödel sentence? Again, intuitively I suspect yes, but it seems impossible to distinguish between a Gödel sentence and a provable theorem that is really, really, really hard to prove.

Comment: Bayesian reasoning requires a model with priors and independence assumptions that I think will be hard to justify in this context. (And of course such reasoning will never amount to a proof.) But it sounds like a good exercise.

Comment: Intuitively is correct; our "confidence" in arithmetic (only recently based on Peano axioms) is quite high (see e.g. accounting). May we measure it in a rigorous way?

Comment: @Karl Yes, it is true a Bayesian approach will never amount to a proof. However, a proof of consistency or a proof that a particular formula is a Godel setence is off the table, so it seems a probabilistic approach attempting to grapple with the inevitable uncertainty is the best one could do. I don't really see the specification of a prior as a problem... couldn't we just make it uniform to represent our ignorance?

Comment: I think you'll see the problems if you try to actually do the quantitative modeling. Is there some rate at which you assume mathematicians make attempts to prove a system inconsistent? Is there some fixed probability with which an attempt succeeds if the system is inconsistent? Are the attempts independent of each other? Etc.